# Define a new math function

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfmath

I want to use an angle (say `a`) in `tikzpicture`, which is calculated from other parameters:

```
\def\d{1}
\def\D{2}
\def\H{5}

a=90+0.5*asin(2(\D-\d)/\H)
```

This angle `a` I then use in a `tikzpicture` environment.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}

  \coordinate (c1) at (0,0);

  \coordinate (c2) at ($(c1)+(\H,0)$);

  \draw (c1) circle (\d/2);

  \draw (c2) circle (\D/2);

  \draw ($(c1)+(\d/2:a)$) to ($(c2)+(\D/2:a)$);

\end{tikzpicture}
```

How do I define this `a`?

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) as is custom on this site, you are much much more likely to get help if you take the time to create a full minimal example others can copy and test as is, instead of posting sniplets like this where others have to guess 50% before they can test your code.

Comment: Using `\def` is discouraged. You will realize why when your paper cites Erdős and you'll get a weird output.

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}

\def\d{1}
\def\D{2}
\def\H{5}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\a}{90+0.5*asin(2*(\D-\d)/\H)}
  \coordinate (c1) at (0,0);
  \coordinate (c2) at ($(c1)+(\H,0)$);
  \draw (c1) circle (\d/2);
  \draw (c2) circle (\D/2);
  \draw ($(c1)+(\d/2:\a)$) to ($(c2)+(\D/2:\a)$);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```